# Where should I put image assets with Foundation 6?

Tags: image, assets, zurb-foundation-6

I'm quite new to Foundation 6, and I don't really understand how to handle images.

Documentation says many things :

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html#asset-copying :

> Gulp will copy anything out of the src/assets folder as-is to the assets folder of your final project. Note that Sass files, JavaScript files, and images are not part of this copying process, as they have their own steps.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html#image-compression :

> By default, all images are copied as-is from assets/img to your dist folder. When building for production, images are run through gulp-imagemin for compression. The plugin supports JPEG, PNG, SVG, and GIF files.

Images located in the `src/assets` folder do not get copied to `dist/assets`. So, does it mean I should copy them manually? What would be the purpose of `src/assets/img`then?

Also, with Foundation 5, I was resizing images in various formats to be used with Interchange. Is there any more efficient process with Foundation 6?

So, how am I supposed to deal with image assets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Zurb Template for your Foundation 6 project? If so, there was a bug that was fixed (1 day prior to this answer) that was preventing the images from getting copied to the `dist` folder.

You only need to remove an exclamation point to fix this. To see where, look at the diff of this PR:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template/pull/25/files

**Answer Source:** https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7552

Comment: Yes. The bug was somehow resolved when I checked back. Files were properly copied.